# Point unreal RunUAT.bat to a custom VS buildtools only copied to a machine (not installed on a machine)

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine5, visual-studio-2017-build-tools, windows-build-tools

The main problem I face is that RunUAT will use vswhere to locate all the buildtools installed on a given machine but therefore it will not find the VS buildtools that I just copied (essentially mounted a disk containing them).

Is there any way to overcome this and manually supply RunUAT (unreal automation tool) with the right .net/c++ build tools? My understanding is that vswhere is being used by default but that one is only aware of the VS buildtools that were properly installed on the same machine.

Context: We are trying to build a CI pipeline that will test the plugin on different versions. Pre-installing all the versions on all the machines is not an option that we can take (disk space limitations).